# TFS Build Definition deletes itself

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild

In TFS2010 I am having trouble creating *Build Definitions*.

I have created a new *Team Project*, added the *Solution* to the *Team Project* and am now trying to create a *Build Definition*.

I click *New Build Definition* in *Team Explorer* set the drop folder under *Build Defaults* and select *Continuous Integration* under *Trigger*.

I leave everything else as default and save the definition.

Next I click *View Builds* and try to queue a build only to get the error message:

> TF42036: There is no build definition available to build the team project Project.Title. Create a new build definition and try again.

In the *Solution Explorer*, the *Build Definition* has disappeared (it was there previously).

Even more strange, when trying to add another *Build Definition*, the Process item has a warning icon against it and no Process Templates are available in the drop down list.

Is this a know issue or am I missing something?

Comment: I would call this one odd.  I just tested adding a build definition exactly how you have against our TFS server and it worked just fine.  Are you sure no one is deleting it out from under you?

Comment: I'm currently the only user, this is a new installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by restarting TFS.

Comment: Someone with the same crazy issue - amazing!

Answer (score 3):

You need to select a Build Process Template, the basic one is called DefaultTemplate.xaml and should be in a folder called BuildProcessTemplates under source control.  If it's not in the drop down list try clicking the New button, Select an Existing XAML File and browsing for it.

You will also need to specify at least one project/solution under the Items To Build when using the default template.

[image: Build Process Template]

Comment: One the first try, this was done automatically. The second time it was not. I have already tired setting these values but have the same issue as above (the definition appears under builds only to vanish when I try to queue up a build).

Comment: A morning reboot of the server and my development PC seem to have resolved the issue. The fields still need to be manually populated but I am now able to create a build definition and queue a build. One of those things I guess.